# Why am I getting a `Data type mismatch` error when I add "CF" to the end of my search string in a SQL statement in Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

The following query (qryCurLotNewProducts) produces a data set that I want process further with another query (qryBNP_CFRecordset):

```
//qryCurLotNewProducts
SELECT tblNewProducts.*
FROM tblNewProducts INNER JOIN tblCurLot ON (tblCurLot.CatalogNum = tblNewProducts.CatalogNum) AND 
(tblNewProducts.LotNum = tblCurLot.CurLot);
```

[image: output from qryCurLotNewProducts]

When I run this second query to list only the "CF" products found in the first query, I get the `Data type mismatch in criteria expression' error.

```
//qryBNP_CFRecordset
SELECT qryCurLotNewProducts.*, tblABCategory.UNSPSC, tblAmount.ProductSize
FROM tblAmount RIGHT JOIN (tblABCategory RIGHT JOIN qryCurLotNewProducts ON tblABCategory.ABCategory = qryCurLotNewProducts.ABCategory) ON tblAmount.Amount = qryCurLotNewProducts.Amount
WHERE (((qryCurLotNewProducts.CatalogNum) Like "A700-###CF") AND ((qryCurLotNewProducts.DateEntered) Between #1/1/2000# And #3/1/2020#))
ORDER BY qryCurLotNewProducts.CatalogNum, Abs(qryCurLotNewProducts.LotNum);
```

If I remove the `CF` from the search string (so "A700-###"), the query correctly outputs a list containing all items that contain that pattern:

[image: non-CF material output]

If I use strings like "A700-####F" or "A700-###ZZ" or other combinations like that, I don't get an error but rather an empty results set.

Notably, "A700-001CF", "A700-002CF", etc all create the data type error. It seems there is something about the CF key combination that is causing trouble.

Has anybody else ever seen this issue? Do I need to use some kind of delimiter to tell SQL to not view CF as some kind of special switch?

Comment: Q: What happens with `"A700-###C?`", `"A700-###?F"`?  Q: Can you tell what "type MSSQL thinks it is?  Two candidates are "numeral" (as you'd expect", or maybe even "date" (who knows?)  Q: What happens if you use single quotes (`'A700-####CF'`) instead of double quotes?

Comment: both of the first suggestions cause the data type mismatch...single quotes, same result.

Comment: I don't know how to answer your second Q.

Comment: I was looking at the tables at play in the first query and the LotNum field does not allow Unicode Compression. These particular lot numbers (9 characters with a mix of letters and numbers) are a new addition to the system. Previously, lot numbers have always been numerals only with a typical max of two digits. Could this have something to do with it?

Comment: So the problem had nothing to do with "CF" per se; the problem was the "join" condition.  CatalogNum values like 'A700-000' happened to match to a *numeric* LotNum ... and CatalogNum values like 'A700-001CF' happened to match to a *text* LotNum.  Hence the "data type mismatch".  Glad you (and heDudeWithHat) found it!

Comment: Yes, when the query tried to run the non-numeric LotNums (associated with the "CF" products) through the absolute value function, it threw the mismatch. I'm adding some features to an existing system and this particular query was already in place...I'm not really sure why the original designer thought it necessary to wrap the LotNum in the `abs()` function. The likelihood of someone entering a negative number in that field is very low.

Comment: Just for SO record, when I moved this wildcard-carrying query over into VBA it produced no results. After a quick search, I learned that you must replace the hashtag with the percent sign...so " `A700-%%%CF` "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Abs(qryCurLotNewProducts.LotNum)` wont work with the values for Products ending in CF. Your LotNum-Column has a text-type.
Edit: Your LotNum-Column has a text-type as you can see in your first screenshot.

Comment: I think you're on to something there TDWH...this is probably going to be your first answered question.